# django - "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str" error

Tags: django, serialization, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

I my django-rest-framework I have the following models:

Basically every ride has one final destination and can have multiple middle destinations.

**models.py:**

```
class Destination(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Ride(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='rides_as_driver')
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination, related_name='rides_as_final_destination')
    leaving_time=models.TimeField()
    num_of_spots=models.IntegerField()
    passengers=models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name="rides_as_passenger")
    mid_destinations=models.ManyToManyField(Destination, related_name='rides_as_middle_destination')
```

**serializers.py - RideSerializer**

```
class RideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    driver = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='driver.user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Ride
        fields = ('driver', 'destination', 'leaving_time',
                  'num_of_spots', 'passengers', 'mid_destinations')
        read_only_fields = ('driver', 'passengers', 'mid_destinations')
```

**Problem is -** When I am trying to POST to /rides/ in order to add a ride - for example `{destination=LA, leaving_time=19:45, num_of_spots=4}`

I get error `"destination":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}`

*couple of questions:*

- What is this error? if I have a destination as a foreign key in the **Ride** model, does it mean that the destination that I am adding has to be already in the **Destinations** table?
- How to fix this error?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the `name` of the related `Destination` object into the serializer, instead of passing the `pk`/`id` of the `Destination` object. So Django REST framework is seeing this and complaining, because it can't resolve `LA` into an object.

It sounds like you may actually be looking for [a `SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield), which allows you to identify objects by a slug (`LA` in this case) instead of their primary keys.

Comment: thanks for your answer. one more question I have - if I use SlugRelatedField like you said, after the creation there is a Ride with a Destination, and the Destination object doesn't exist in the Destination table, right? isn't that a problem is a ForeignKey relation? I mean, shouldn't a foreign key be a reference to an existing object in another table? thanks again

Comment: @OfekAgmon DRF does not deal with automatically creating related objects. You would need to [override `.create`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) to create the destination if it didn't exist.

Comment: got it. and also, with SlugRelatedField, two scenatios I wonder about: 1. I POST "LA" (LA doesn't exist in Destinations table) and it adds it to Ride table, right? 2. If I POST with "NY" and "NY" is already in the Destination table, with a connection be created between the "NY" Ride object and the "NY" Destination object? thanks a lot again

Comment: @OfekAgmon `SlugRelatedField` looks up in the database for an object with that slug, so yes that should work as you described it. If you want to [open a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/359284/kevin-brown) about this, we can talk about it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case, I had to remove the read_only/many fields from the SlugRelatedField and add the `queryset=Destination.objects.all()` field for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a minor difference between Django and Django Rest Framework whenever we try to add the Foreign key references to an instance

Let us assume we want to add the user references to another DB Table

### Django

In Django, we reference the whole instance of the user as mentioned below

```
user = request.user
```

### Django Rest Framework

However in DRF if we follow the same procedure we get the errors like

> Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str/User type

In order to overcome this error, we need to reference the Primary Key of the table instead (Here **id** is the PK)

```
user = request.user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

**Angular/Django Rest Framework**

I had similar problem when trying to post a formdata that has a field with some array values. It turned out that I was using a wrong content-type in the post headers of angular frontend. All I needed was comment out Content-Type.

```
  Post(endpoint, postData) {
    let auth = `Bearer ${this.token}`;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: auth
    });
    let fullurl = `${this.baseUrl}${endpoint}`;
   .....
  ....
}
```