# Rest Call gives error : Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This post has an update below.

I currently have these two models. I am trying to create a job using `CreateAPIView`. Before I show the view here are my models

```
class modelJobCategory(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    other = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False , blank=True , null=True)


class modelJob(models.Model):
    category            = models.ManyToManyField(modelJobCategory,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    description         = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
```

These two are my serializers

```
class Serializer_CreateJobCategory(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = modelJobCategory
        fields = [
            'description',
        ]

class Serializer_CreateJob(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
        category = Serializer_CreateJobCategory
        fields = [
            'category',
            'description',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        job = modelJob.objects.create(user=user,category=?,...) #How to get category ?
        return job
```

Now this is my view

```
class CreateJob_CreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = Serializer_CreateJob
    queryset = modelJob.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = Serializer_CreateJob(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now I am passing the following JSON

```
{
"category" :{   
             "description": "Foo"   
            },
"description" : "World"
}
```

However I get the exception

```
{
  "category": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
  ]
}
```

I came across the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764437/django-incorrect-type-expected-pk-value-received-str-error) and it mentions i need to define a slug field which I am not sure where. Any suggestion on how I can fix this ?

**Update:**

So my create Job serializer looks like this now however it returns back the error

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `category`
>   on serializer `Serializer_CreateJob`. The serializer field might be
>   named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `modelJob`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has
>   no attribute 'description'.

```
class Serializer_CreateJob(ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.description')
    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
        category = Serializer_CreateJobCategory()
        fields = [
            'category',
            'description',
        ]

   def create(self, validated_data):
        category_data = validated_data.pop('category')
        category = modelJobCategory.objects.get(description=category_data['description'])
        job = modelJob.objects.create(description=validated_data["description"])
        job.category.add(category)
        job.save()
        return job
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this now ?

Comment: Are you trying to create both `modelJobCategory` and `modelJob` as part of this View?

Comment: nope I have a Category whose description is Foo (as mentioned in Json being posted ) and I want to add that category to modelJob

Comment: Also, AFAIK field declarations should happen as class attrs and not in meta; why have we defined `category = Serializer_CreateJobCategory` inside the meta class? I might be missing something so please lmk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
class Serializer_CreateJob(ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        queryset=modelJobCategory.objects.all(),
        slug_field='description'
    ) 
    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
        fields = [
            'category',
            'description',
        ]
```

Comment: I get the error `{
  "category": [
    "Expected a list of items but got type \"str\"."
  ]
}`

Comment: @MistyD try to pass category as list of strings: `{ "category": ["name"]}`

Comment: Given that category is a M2M field, you can change your category to a list as neverwalkaloner mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Try to explicitly define category field and use [`source=category.description`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Serializer_CreateJob(ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.description') 
    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
        category = Serializer_CreateJobCategory
        fields = [
            'category',
            'description',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_data = validated_data.pop('category')
        category = Category.objects.get(description=category_data['description'])  
        job = modelJob.objects.create(description=validated_data['description'],category=category,...) #categy object found by it's description
        return job
```

Comment: I am getting the error on  `category = serializers.CharFields(source='category.description')` which is  `<class 'tuple'>: (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'CharFields'",), None)`

Comment: @MistyD oops, it should be `CharField`.

Comment: yup i should have figured that out. I am trying it now

Comment: on validation in the view I get the error `{
  "category": [
    "Not a valid string."
  ]
}`

Comment: @MistyD how do you pass category? I suppose it should be something like this: `{'category': 'name1'}`.

Comment: I am passing it as `{
"category" :{   
             "description": "Foo"   
            },
"description" : "World"
}` Is this wrong ?

Comment: @MistyD tryto post `{'category': 'Foo', "description" : "World" }`

Comment: So after I return the job object I get the exception `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `category` on serializer `Serializer_CreateJob`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `modelJob` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'description'.`