# Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict. Django Rest Framwork - Vue

Tags: python, django, vue.js

I'm new to Django and Django Rest Framework. This is a little project I'm trying to do to improve my skills but I've been stuck here a lot of time.

ViewSets.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from .models import Plazo, Perfil, Solicitud, Estatus
from .serializers import (PlazoSerializer, PerfilSerializer, 
SolicitudSerializer, EstatusSerializer, 
SolicitudExpandeSerializer)


class PlazoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Plazo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlazoSerializer


 class EstatusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Estatus.objects.all()
     serializer_class = EstatusSerializer


 class PerfilViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Perfil.objects.all()
     serializer_class = PerfilSerializer


class SolicitudViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Solicitud.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SolicitudSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serializer_class

        if self.action in ['list', 'retrieve']:
            serializer_class = SolicitudExpandeSerializer

        return serializer_class
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Plazo, Perfil, Solicitud, Estatus


class PlazoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Plazo
        fields = '__all__'


class EstatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Estatus
        fields = '__all__'


class PerfilSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = '__all__'


class SolicitudSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Solicitud
        fields = '__all__'


class SolicitudExpandeSerializer(SolicitudSerializer):

    perfil = PerfilSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)
    status = EstatusSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Plazo(models.Model):
    plazo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meses = models.IntegerField()
    intereses = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'plazo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'plazos'


class Perfil(models.Model):
    perfil_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'perfiles'


class Estatus(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nombre)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'estatus'
        verbose_name_plural = 'estatus'


class Solicitud(models.Model):

    ACEPTADO, PENDIENTE, RECHAZADO = range(1, 4)

    ESTADOS = (
        (ACEPTADO, 'Aceptado'),
        (PENDIENTE, 'Pendiente'),
        (RECHAZADO, 'Rechazado')
    )

    solicitud_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    monto = models.IntegerField()
    tarjeta_de_credito = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    plazo = models.ForeignKey(Plazo, related_name='SolicitudPlazo', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, related_name='SolicitudPerfil', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Estatus, related_name='SolicitudEstatus', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    mostrar = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.solicitud_id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'solicitud'
        verbose_name_plural = 'solicitudes'
```

JS

```
    updateSolicitud: function() {
     this.loading = true;
     this.$http.put(`/api/solicitud/${this.currentSolicitud.solicitud_id}/`, 
     this.currentSolicitud)
            .then((response) => {
              this.loading = false;
              this.currentSolicitud = response.data;
              this.getSolicitudes();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              this.loading = false;
              console.log(err);
            })
      }
```

When I try to update a record I get this error. I've tried passing the "Perfil" value from an input but it still don't recognize it and creates a dictionary.

> "{"perfil":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."],"status":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."]}"

Comment: Check this link; maybe it would help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764437/django-incorrect-type-expected-pk-value-received-str-error

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your ProfileSerializer is expecting a number, specifically the 'pk' of the object you are trying to update, and at the moment you are sending a json to the server that has a dictionary.

Your server is expecting a json with this format to update the Profile.

```
{
  "id": "1", (or whichever id you are trying to update
  "nombre": "New Name for your profile",
}
```

I would recommend checking the json you are sending to the server.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I sending an incorrect format json. So I did this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764437/django-incorrect-type-expected-pk-value-received-str-error

Answer (score 1):

Only placing this here since this was the top search result, but the situation that I ran into was that I had a **nested serializer**.

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the field name to the `exclude` attribute of the `Meta` class, since I didn't need the results of that field to be serialized for the particular serializer.

for example:

```
class SolicitudSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Solicitud
        exclude = ('field_name', )
```