# Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str in DRF.(one to one field)

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

When I send post request with data in profile model at that time this error show.

### Error

> {
> "user_name": [
> "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
> ] }

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771110/14131913) but don't know how to implement SlugRelatedField in serializers(OneToOneField)

**models.py:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()
     
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=80,
        unique=True,
    )
    
    email = models.EmailField(
                unique=True,
                blank=True,         
                )
    .....

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.username)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(to = CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=15, blank=True)
    public_name = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=15, blank=True)
    ....
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user_name','full_name','public_name']
```

**views.py:**

```
class ProfileApiview(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Pradip - Have a look at this.

```
 class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ['user_name','full_name','public_name']
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            profile = Profile.objects.create(
                user_name=user, full_name=validated_data['full_name'].............)
            return profile
```

Comment: Thanks to reply.  ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000218653D3C70>": "Profile.user_name" must be a "CustomUser" instance.  How to solve this error?

Comment: @Pradip - Can you specify what sort of authentication you are using. My code was based on SessionAuthentication.

Comment: I use JSONWebTokenAuthentication

Comment: @Pradip-  I am not sure about the JWT.But this article might help https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: @Pradip- Is there a specific reason you are opting for JWT?

Comment: @Stacy Thank you so much.Your code is work perfactly when I 
 put `profile =Profile(user_name=user,full_name=validated_data['full_name']) profile.save()` instead of `profile = Profile.objects.create(
                user_name=user, full_name=validated_data['full_name'])`

Comment: @Pradip- Glad I could help.